# Import data from mysql to postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models in my ruby app (jurnal and jurnal_my) and i need to import data jurnal from mysql to postgresql.

This is my method :

jurnal_my.rb

```
  establish_connection "mysql"
  self.table_name = "jurnal"

  def self.import_from_mysql
    JurnalMy.all.each{|jurnal|
      hash = {}
      JurnalMy.first.attributes.delete_if{|attr|%w(ID CREATED_AT UPDATED_AT).include?(attr)}.map{|case_attr|case_attr}.each{|hash_attr|
        hash = hash.merge(hash_attr[0].downcase => hash_attr[1])
      }
        Jurnal.create hash
    }
  end
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: adit
  password: xxxxxxx
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: portalpos_development

mysql:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  username: root
  password: xxxxxxx
  database: app

test:
  <<: *default
  database: portalpos_test
```

When i try to import data to postgresql, it's working. But the result is wrong.
Data jurnal in mysql :

```
J01
J02
J03
```

Data jurnal in postgresql (result) :

```
J01
J01
J01
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `JurnalMy.first`, hence you're only creating the first record. You should call `attributes` on `jurnal`. Also better to use [find_each](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each) instead of loading all the records on memory.

```
JurnalMy.find_each do |jurnal|
  hash = {}
  jurnal.attributes # ...
  Jurnal.create hash
end
```

Comment: I have try your method. Its work. But if I have 5 datum and import for twice. How to protect the postgres from duplicate data?

Comment: Maybe you could use [first_or_create](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create) for this. It'll be `Jurnal.where(hash).first_or_create`